# How do I unpack a list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, join, tuples

In Python 3 I'm trying to unpack a list of lists:

```
members = [['3', '5', '5', '20', 'D'], ['2', '2', '2', '30', 'C']]
```

I want it  to print in the format of

```
3 5 5 20 D
2 2 2 30 C
```

I've tried using `print (' '.join(members)),` but I keep getting the error:

> ```
> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
members = [['3', '5', '5', '20', 'D'], ['2', '2', '2', '30', 'C']]
for item in members:
    print ' '.join(item)
```

Answer (score 4):

As this is a nested list, when you do:

```
print (' '.join(members))
```

You're really trying to join each "sublist" using a space. The error you're seeing is because Python is unable to convert the whole "sublist" to a string. You're on the right track, though!

You could do this using a list comprehension:

```
print(*[' '.join(m) for m in members], sep="\n")
```

Or a generator expression:

```
print(*(' '.join(m) for m in members), sep="\n")
```

Or a loop:

```
for member in members:
    print(*member)
```

Or also in a loop:

```
for member in members:
    print(' '.join(member))
```

The `*` operator unpacks a list into comma-separated arguments (to put it in simple terms).

Answer (score 2):

You need to act on each member of `members` in some way. Here are a couple options to start you off.

Iterate over each member and unpack it:

```
>>> for m in members: print(*m)
...
3 5 5 20 D
2 2 2 30 C
```

Join each member and unpack the whole thing:

```
>>> print(*(' '.join(m) for m in members), sep='\n')
3 5 5 20 D
2 2 2 30 C
```

Answer (score 2):

You can *unpack* the inner `list` in your `print`

```
for member in members:
      print(*member)
# 3 5 5 20 D
# 2 2 2 30 C
```

Answer (score 2):

In python

```
" ".join(["a", "b", "c"])
```

produces

```
"a b c"
```

If you want a single string as result for your data what you can do is simply nesting two of these expressions:

```
result = "\n".join(" ".join(L) for L in members)
```

separating with a newline `"\n"` elements obtained by separating with space `" "` items in each list.

If you just want print the data however a simple loop is easier to read:

```
for L in members:
    print(" ".join(L))
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked

```
for member in members:
    print " ".join(member)
```